# Is it possible to use the AOC-SAS2LP-MV8 HBA (Marvell 9480) on XenServer?

Tags: xenserver

If not, is there any other hypervisor OS that supports them?

Marvell 9480 has drivers for RHEL/Fedora, so i think that they should work even under XenServer. I don't know how.

Answer (score 1):

I like to build everything in xen from source, and when I do so I have no problem with Xen,  and some cards that use this controller. I am using a 3.8.5 kernel. Used this guide and built in any unmentioned xen/virtio/drivers for my hardware: http://blog.tidyhosts.com/index.php/howto-install-xen-dom0-on-centos-6-from-source